# Python Threading, MatPlotLib, and loops

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-multithreading

I have a repeated graphing call inside of a loop. Because the backend needs to continue running, I have split the graphing off into another thread (using interactive mode locks up the graph, since the backend is using subprocess calls to C++). However, this appears to cause issues when the backend comes around to the graphing again. While it continues to run, the graphing fails after the first time. I need it to be able to keep opening added windows as long as the code is running, so the user can leave and come back later and still have all the graphs up. How can I bring up as many windows as needed, and keep them there even if the underlying code finishes (windows likes to close all CMD windows the second code stops executing)?

```
import subprocess
import threading
from matplotlib import pyplot as mpl
...
for x in data:
...
   if condition:
...
      class Graph(threading.Thread):
          def __init__(self,X,Y,min_tilt, min_energy):
              self.X = X
              self.Y = Y
              self.min_tilt = min_tilt
              self.min_energy = min_energy
              threading.Thread.__init__(self)

          def run(self):
              X = self.X
              Y = self.Y
              dx = (X.max()-X.min())/30.0
              x = np.arange(X.min(),X.max()+dx,dx)
              y = quad(x,fit)
              fig = mpl.figure()
              ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
              ax.grid(True)
              ax.plot(x, y, 'g')
              ax.scatter(X, Y, c='b')
              ax.scatter(self.min_tilt, self.min_energy, c='r')
              mpl.show()
     thread = Graph(X,Y,min_tilt,min_energy)
     thread.start()
 ....
   subprocess.Popen(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a complex setup simply to run your plots in a non blocking way. Does interactive mode not cut the mustard?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.interactive(True)

# complex code which produces multiple figures goes here...

# ... and might do something like 
fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.draw()

# ... or this
fig2 = plt.figure()
plt.polar(range(10))
plt.draw()

# once everything is done, we can put in a blocking call
# which will terminate when the last window is closed by the user
plt.show(block=True)
```

Comment: Interactive mode does not work. If you use it the plot opens as a white 'not responding' window and crashes the program when you close it. If you add a delay, you can get the plot to open, but closing it still crashes everything. Also, your solution is not completely usable anyway since we do not know in advance how many plots there will be, hence why they are inside the for loop.

Comment: I have the same problem as Elliot said.